# How can I fix drooping vinyl siding?

Tags: repair, vinyl-siding

I have vinyl siding on my new home. Starting about a week ago, one segment of siding detached on one end and is drooping. The other side is attached just fine.

I tried snapping it back into place, as it looks like each is just supposed to stay in place by snapping into each other. That lasts for about a few hours, and it starts to sag in the middle and eventually the same end detaches and droops again.

My father in law suggested using a galvanized nail and hammer in the siding, but seems like a brute force bandaid. Is he right? What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though the panels snap to each other they are nailed to the wall at the top edge of the panel. So it's probably a good idea to nail it back. Just make sure it's a little loose because the panels expand and shrink a lot depending on outside temperature.

Comment: I checked: The panel itself was never nailed near the top as you described. Is it possible they just missed that nail? It was fine for 5 months. I guess the heat warped it?

Comment: I went ahead and just hammered this in. Thanks for the advice.